# Using [SKScene sceneWithSize:] to scale up iPad version

Tags: ios, ipad, sprite-kit

I am working on a Sprite Kit game and was about to adjust image sizes and add ~iPads to scale up for the bigger screen. But I just thought that I could do the following:

```
    if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)) {
            scene = [Menu sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.width/2, skView.bounds.size.height/2)];
    } else scene = [Menu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

      scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

      [skView presentScene:scene];
```

This work well, as my graphics are originally big and are shrunk with code. (If I use this method I will make them the max size.)

Is this alright to due, as this way my SKPhysics (jumping) does not need to change when on iPad? The only problem I found was with text and SKLabelNodes, since they are drawn small then scaled.

Thanks for any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: this will upscale the iPad version, degrading its quality (blurry, less detail). Apple might not approve.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thats a good point, but because my original png files are the right size for iPad Retina (in fact bigger) and there is no visible quality loss. Thanks for the idea of rejection though, did not think of that.

Comment: Have you done a side-by-side comparison? I'd be surprised if there was no noticable loss in image quality. Also keep in mind that using images of higher resolution than the device can handle is essentially a waste of memory, ie a @2x texture uses 4 times as much memory while non-Retina devices typically have less memory available, too. Is less of an issue for iPad textures used on Retina iPhones though.

Comment: I did not think about memory either, I just tested and it won't work for me anyway, as the physics of jumping changes due to a slightly taller landscape screen (proportionate). But thanks for the help nonetheless.